# How can it be that a file with full file path Can Not be found?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have a few lines of a Gradle script and with some Groovy methods that I want to use as a base for testing a few ideas around project testing and configuration.  There are existing scripts involved that need to use the (Java) construct: **File** (as opposed to the Gradle `file()` method).

The script runs *perfectly* on the command line and in Netbeans as long as I supply the complete Absolute File Path to the `Properties.load()` call.

Later, when run build (again in  Netbeans) using a legal relative path and file name my little function fails to find the the file (*at all*!).  That can happen.  But in this case; the Java `File.getAbsolutePath()` method show the  identical string in all cases. Working and the Fail case.  I prepared this using Linux.  The results are produced  on Windows 10.

There must be a reason.  I'm blowed if I can see what it could be at this point.  The Gradle,

- **[Working with Files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html)** section

  - says relative file paths are OK.
- Java - [Writing System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

  - [System.setProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
  - I myself was a little dubious about using `user.dir` - However the docs seem to back it up, been there since Java 1.2
  - It works not only with Gradle; in Java and Groovy too.
  - Same as `-Duser.dir=`*`pathString`*

***Failing* output**:

```
    ============  project  ============
Gradle version: 3.4.1
Groovy version: 2.4.7
Java version:   1.8.0_121

Root project:       'try'
  project dir:      '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle'
  cwd:              '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle'

    ===================================

  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[ loadProperties testing ]xxxx

  cwd:      '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle'
  user.dir: '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle' ...
  loading:  'common.properties' ...
  loading:  '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle/common.properties' ...

 * No Such File: '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle/common.properties'.

  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[ loadProperties end     ]xxxx
```

***Working* output**:

```
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[ loadProperties testing ]xxxx

  cwd:      '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle'
  user.dir: '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle' ...
  loading:  '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle/common.properties' ...
  loading:  '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle/common.properties' ...

    'ext.zzz' => "ext.zzz"
    'zzz' => "zzz"

  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[ loadProperties end     ]xxxx
```

The Gradle `build.gradle` script is quite simple with a few lines to report on the runtime environment and software versions, etc.

**`build.gradle`  script**:

```
import  org.gradle.api.artifacts.*

System.setProperty( "user.dir", project.rootDir.toString() )

    /****
     *  try-s project 
     *****/

println  "";

apply plugin: 'base' // To add "clean" task to the root project.


    println  "\n    ============  project  ============";
    println  "Gradle version: "+ gradle.gradleVersion;
    println  "Groovy version: "+ GroovySystem.version;
    println  "Java version:   "+ System.getProperty("java.version");
    println  "";
    println  "Root project:       '${project.rootProject.name}'";
//  println  "  root dir:         '${project.rootDir}'";
    println  "  project dir:      '${project.projectDir}'";
    println  "  cwd:              '${(new File(".")).getCanonicalPath()}'";
//  println  "  user dir:         '${System.getProperty("user.dir")}'";
    println  "";
    println  "    ===================================\n";

println  "  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[ loadProperties testing ]xxxx"
println  ""

  //  Does Not Work:
  //    File.exists() --> false
  //
  loadProperties( "common.properties" );

  //  Works - fully qualified file path:
  //    File.exists() --> true
  //    and then loads properties from the file  
  //
  loadProperties( "/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle/common.properties" );

  //  Works - using project.rootDir property
  //
  loadProperties( "${project.rootDir}/common.properties" );

  //  Works - using a path relative to the Netbeans start directory
  //    Only works when `System.user.dir` has the
  //       same value as the start directory
  //    Obviously the path must be relative to 
  //       Netbeans start-up directory -- Likely 
  //       to change for different locations, etc.
  //
loadProperties( "../../../sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle/common.properties" );

println  ""
println  "  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[ loadProperties end     ]xxxx"
```

**`loadProperties()` function**:

```
private def loadProperties( String fileName )
{
    File        propFile    = new File( fileName );
    Properties  fileProps   = new Properties( );

      //  Check current directory
      //
    println  "  cwd:      '${(new File(".")).getCanonicalPath()}'";
    println  "  user.dir: '${System.getProperty("user.dir")}' ...";
    println  "  loading:  '${fileName}' ...";
    println  "  loading:  '${propFile.getCanonicalPath()}' ...";
    println  "";

    if( propFile.exists() )
    {
        InputStream propStream  = new FileInputStream( propFile );  //  fileName );
        fileProps.load( propStream );

        fileProps.each { prop, val ->

            println  "    '${prop}' => \"${val}\"";
        }
    }
    else {
        println " * No Such File: '${propFile.getAbsolutePath()}'."
    }

} //loadProperties
```

Unfortunately without the `if( propFile.exists() )` check Gradle reports an excepton: `FileNotFoundException` (oddly enough).

Looking at the output of the **`propFile.getAbsolutePath()`** and either the Fully Qualified file name string or the `rootDir+"common.properties` version of events -- All Four scenarios show  the ***identical*** file-path-name string:

> '/home/projects/sandbox/lab/gradle-lab/try-gradle/common.properties'

For me the bottom line is, How May two Identical File Paths be processed and ONE of FOUR, just one valid file pathname is Not Found by the JVM / Gradle partnership.

ps.

I already know the Gradle plugin has a bug concerning Not  starting with the project dir as the current directory.  By choice (apparently). I fix that with `user.dir` setting -- Unfortunately commenting that line makes no difference to the results.  As long as the paths are correct.

Comment: WRT the `user.dir` property, I don't believe this changes the CWD in a trustable way...  Feels like this is a NetBeans bug?

Comment: @tim_yates ... Yes, however everything I've see says this is the way it is done (since java 1.2).  Same as `Java ... -Duser.dir=` *`pathString`* -- Which does work.

Answer (score 0):

Quite surprising. It is working.

build.gradle:

```
System.setProperty( "user.dir", project.rootDir.toString() )

apply plugin: 'base' // To add "clean" task to the root project.
println  " user dir:         ${System.getProperty('user.dir')}"
loadProperties('common.properties')


println  "ends"
def loadProperties(file){
    def properties = new Properties()
    def propertiesFile = new File(file)
    if( propertiesFile.exists() ) println 'file exists'
    propertiesFile.withInputStream {
        properties.load(it)
    }
    println properties
}
```

**Output** is seen as expected

```
$ gradle 
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
 user dir:         /home/rsettine/Documents/gradle
file exists
{abc=1, test=1}
ends
:help

Welcome to Gradle 3.3.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.263 secs
```

Comment: Thanks @Rao ... I was feeling flummoxed there for a bit. It does not work on Windows or Linux for me.  THEN ... I looked at your output again -- You are running on the command line (shell) not from **Netbeans**.

Comment: Ok. Do you confirm that it is working from command line on your machine?

Comment: Oh yes -- works from bash and windows cmd.  It seems the Netbeqans gradle communicates with a Gradle deamon so it must run in a slightly different environment.  I don't get *how* the same file path string can give different outcomes.... <scratching head>

Comment: Try changing from `common.properties` to `./common.properties` and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks Rao -- Actually, that does not address the point of the question.  Two identical file names can give different results.  Under **every operating system** I know of, that MUST-BE the same file if it is just there on disk, untouched (which it is).  And it is when we run on the command console.  There's something very _strange_ happening.